# excessive lag when dragging windows

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, lag

When I try to drag windows around (and some other times) everything will stop responding to my clicks, but the mouse still moves fine and videos still play smoothly. Sometimes it will take multiple minutes to start working again, and in that time I don't hear my fans ramping up or anything that would mean that my processor is working hard.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in a vm on a mac host system using virtualbox

host specs: 8gb ram, 1.4 ghz 4 core i5, intel iris plus graphics 1536 MB

VM specs: 5gb ram, 1 cpu, 256 mb vram

I'm new to linux and to virtual machines so I am probably doing something wrong